# Notepad++ replace every 3rd and 4th iteration

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm using notepad++ I'm wondering if it's possible to replace every 3rd and 4th iteration in lines of HTML.

The original code looks like:

```
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"
```

reoccurring...

I need to change every second block of two to look like this.

```
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"
<div class="ui-bar bg ui-bar-d"
<div class="ui-bar bg ui-bar-d"
```

reoccurring...

Are there any regular expressions that will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your HTML looks like

```
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" ... and something else ... (newline)
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" ... and something else ... (newline)
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" ... and something else ... (newline)
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" ... and something else ... (newline)
... etc...
```

and assume that you wish to keep the `... and something else ...` part.

At search field, try

```
(<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d".*\r\n)(<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d".*\r\n)<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"(.*\r\n)<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d"(.*\r\n)
```

Replace with

```
\1\2<div class="ui-bar bg ui-bar-d"\3<div class="ui-bar bg ui-bar-d"\4
```

Depending on whether you are using Windows or UNIX type EOL (i.e. newline character), you may need to change all `\r\n` into `\n`.

---

A more generalized regex that replace only `ui-bar ui-bar-d` clause:

```
(.*ui-bar ui-bar-d.*\r\n)(.*ui-bar ui-bar-d.*\r\n)(.*)ui-bar ui-bar-d(.*\r\n)(.*)ui-bar ui-bar-d(.*\r\n)
```

and replace with

```
\1\2\3ui-bar bg ui-bar-d\4\5ui-bar bg ui-bar-d\6
```

Comment: I really appreciate the reply, it looks like exactly what I need, although I can't get it to work for love nor money, I tried a few variations of your suggestion but to no avail. I just get the "Can't find text" error when I try to replace. I'm using I'm using windows and you're correct in saying there's more to the HTML. An example of a full line looks like `<div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="">Superuser</div></div>
`

Comment: So there's an additional string (`<div class="ui-block-a">`) on each line before the pattern.  You will need to modify the search pattern in that case; I revised my answer to make the search pattern more general.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answers my question and helps me to understand how regex syntax works.